# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement in Ecllips

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to execute the below query from Ecllips i am getting the following error.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select"
+"sum(pr.amount)"
+"from trans_log tl,"
+"payment_detail pp,"
+"pft_trans_reltn pr,"
+"pft_encntr pe,"
+"encounter e,"
+"account a"
+"where"
+"pr.beg_effective_dt_tm >= TO_DATE('01/JUN/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') AND pr.beg_effective_dt_tm <= TO_DATE('30/JUN/2015 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss')"
+"and pp.payment_detail_id=tl.payment_detail_id"
+"and tl.activity_id=pr.activity_id"
+"and tl.active_ind=1"
+"and tl.trans_type_cd=10982.00"
+"and pr.parent_entity_name='PFTENCNTR'"
+"and pe.pft_encntr_id=pr.parent_entity_id"
+"and a.acct_id=pe.acct_id"
+"and a.acct_type_cd=649377.00"
+"and pe.encntr_id=e.encntr_id"
+"and e.organization_id=589723.00");
```

I have tried as suggested in this post [Oracle Post Link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00900_invalid_sql_statement.htm)

I am unable to figure out where i am going wrong.

I've tried to add single quotes, but same error:

> pr.beg_effective_dt_tm >= TO_DATE(\"01/JUN/2015 00:00:00\", \"dd/mm/yy
>   hh24:mi:ss\")
>
> Errr:java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00900:

Comment: you need whitespaces in between the statements

Comment: i have removed the white space and statements i wrote the entire query in single line but got same error

Comment: the db i interacting with is oracle is so i have added oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add whitespaces on every line. Try to use like this:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select"
+" sum(pr.amount)"
+" from trans_log tl,"
+" payment_detail pp,"
+" pft_trans_reltn pr,"
+" pft_encntr pe,"
+" encounter e,"
+" account a"
+" where"
+" pr.beg_effective_dt_tm >= TO_DATE('01/JUN/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss') AND pr.beg_effective_dt_tm <= TO_DATE('30/JUN/2015 23:59:59', 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss')"
+" and pp.payment_detail_id=tl.payment_detail_id"
+" and tl.activity_id=pr.activity_id"
+" and tl.active_ind=1"
+" and tl.trans_type_cd=10982.00"
+" and pr.parent_entity_name='PFTENCNTR'"
+" and pe.pft_encntr_id=pr.parent_entity_id"
+" and a.acct_id=pe.acct_id"
+" and a.acct_type_cd=649377.00"
+" and pe.encntr_id=e.encntr_id"
+" and e.organization_id=589723.00");
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("select"
+"sum(pr.amount)"
```

then the string of the sql that it is trying to execute is

```
selectsum(pr.amount)
```

as you can see you need some white space.

Also the date mask

```
TO_DATE('01/JUN/2015 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss')
```

is incorrect, try using `MON`  instead of `mm`

see http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: yes thanks for the help i am getting the following error nw java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended